# Display order activity by date by location

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Edit: Apologize for not including better sample data.

Looking for some help with a SQL query to report on sales activity by date and location. The intention is to see by day and location how many orders were received, how many were fulfilled, and how many still need to be fulfilled.

Table format

```
Order_ID,Location,Customer,Order_Placed_at,Order_fulfilled_at
1,A,Cust 1,1/1/2015 12:45,1/5/2015 13:00
2,B,Cust 2,1/5/2015 17:00,NULL
3,A,Cust 3,1/4/2015 14:00,1/6/2015 14:00
4,B,Cust 4,1/2/2015 14:00,1/3/2015 14:00
5,A,Cust 5,1/5/2015 18:00,1/6/2015 6:00
6,A,Cust 6,1/3/2015 14:00,1/6/2015 14:00
7,B,Cust 7,1/7/2015 14:00,1/8/2015 14:00
8,A,Cust 8,1/8/2015 14:00,NULL
```

Desired result

```
Date,Location,Orders Placed,Orders Fulfilled,Unfulfilled_orders
12/31/2014,A,0,0,0
12/31/2014,B,0,0,0
1/1/2015,A,1,0,1
1/1/2015,B,0,0,0
1/2/2015,A,0,0,1
1/2/2015,B,1,0,1
1/3/2015,A,1,0,2
1/3/2015,B,0,1,0
1/4/2015,A,1,0,3
1/4/2015,B,0,0,0
1/5/2015,A,1,1,3
1/5/2015,B,1,0,1
1/6/2015,A,0,3,0
1/6/2015,B,0,0,0
1/7/2015,A,0,0,0
1/7/2015,B,1,0,1
1/8/2015,A,1,0,1
1/8/2015,B,0,1,0
1/9/2015,A,0,0,1
1/9/2015,B,0,0,0
```

I am able to query the three count columns individually, but am struggling to find a way to return this in one result set. Especially when I am trying to include dates that do not exist in my table such as 1/9/2015.

```
select date, location, count(*) as Unfulfilled_orders
from [TABLE]
where order_placed <= '01/02/2015' and order_fulfilled_at is null)
group by date, location
```

Comment: Kindly format your question properly.

Comment: Your desired results make no sense without sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Your desired result is incorect against provided data sample

2.To get daily tracking of the required data, you need keep calendar table on server or as in example below

So, my variant of the solution below

```
--Create temp table for OP sample data

IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#yourdata') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #yourdata
SELECT  *
INTO    #yourdata
FROM    ( VALUES ( 1, 'A', 'Cust 1', '2015-01-01 12:45', '2015-01-05 13:00'),
        ( 2, 'B', 'Cust 2', '2015-01-05 17:00', NULL),
        ( 3, 'A', 'Cust 3', '2015-01-04 14:00', '2015-01-06 14:00'),
        ( 4, 'B', 'Cust 4', '2015-01-02 14:00', '2015-01-03 14:00'),
        ( 5, 'A', 'Cust 5', '2015-01-05 18:00', '2015-01-06 6:00'),
        ( 6, 'A', 'Cust 6', '2015-01-03 14:00', '2015-01-06 14:00'),
        ( 7, 'B', 'Cust 7', '2015-01-07 14:00', '2015-01-08 14:00'),
        ( 8, 'A', 'Cust 8', '2015-01-08 14:00', NULL) ) AS T ( Order_ID, Location, Customer, Order_Placed_at, Order_fulfilled_at ) 

--Create temp table for calendar with locations

IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#calendar') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #calendar;
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   CONVERT(DATE, '20141231') AS [Dt]
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   DATEADD(DAY, 1, Dt)
               FROM     cte
               WHERE    dt < CONVERT(DATE, '20160101')
             )
    SELECT  A.Dt ,
            B.Location
    INTO    #calendar
    FROM    cte AS A
            CROSS JOIN ( SELECT *
                         FROM   ( VALUES ( 'A'), ( 'B') ) AS B ( Location ) 
                       ) AS B
OPTION  ( MAXRECURSION 366 )


--final query

SELECT  C.Location ,
        C.Dt ,
        COUNT(Y.Order_ID) AS [Orders Placed] ,
        COUNT(Y.Order_fulfilled_at) AS [Orders Fulfilled] ,
        COUNT(Y.Order_ID) - COUNT(Y.Order_fulfilled_at) AS [Unfulfilled orders]
FROM    #calendar AS C
        LEFT JOIN #yourdata AS Y ON C.Dt = CONVERT(DATE, Y.Order_Placed_at)
                                    AND C.Location = Y.Location
WHERE   C.Dt BETWEEN '20141231' AND '20150109'
GROUP BY C.Location ,
        C.Dt
ORDER BY C.Dt ,
        C.Location
```

output result

[image]

Comment: Will test this first thing in the morning and provide feedback. Really appreciate your time in helping with this.

Comment: Vasily - Your solution has greatly helped me. Only issue is the unfulfilled orders is not persisting day over day but I can take care of that part.